# Kubernetes InvalidVolume.ZoneMismatch despite node affinity specifying availability zone

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

As part of a gitlab CI/CD pipeline, a job should be scheduled and deployed on a Kubernetes pod that has an EBS volume attached to its node. The EBS volume is in `us-east-1c`. I have the following `affinity` section specified in my `runner-chart-values.yaml`:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
          operator: In
          values:
          - us-east-1c
```

which, as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity), means that the node *must* have an availability zone of `us-east-1c`. I know for a fact that there is exactly one node in the relevant EKS cluster that has an availability zone of `us-east-1c`.

When the gitlab runner executes, the job fails:

```
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  1s  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach 
failed for volume "<volume-name>" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not attach volume "<volume-id>" to node "<instance-id>": could not attach volume 
"<volume-id>" to node "<instance-id>": InvalidVolume.ZoneMismatch: The volume '<volume-id>' is not in 
the same availability zone as instance '<instance-id>'
```

How could this be happening? I have verified that the node is available when the job runs, but even if that were not the case wouldn't the scheduler wait until it was available (and possibly timeout) rather than use a node in the wrong availability zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to specify the node affinity in the `runners` section of the config file to apply the requirements to the *job* pods, not the controller pod:

```
config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        [runners.kubernetes.affinity]
          [runners.kubernetes.affinity.node_affinity]
            [runners.kubernetes.affinity.node_affinity.required_during_scheduling_ignored_during_execution]
              [[runners.kubernetes.affinity.node_affinity.required_during_scheduling_ignored_during_execution.node_selector_terms]]
                [[runners.kubernetes.affinity.node_affinity.required_during_scheduling_ignored_during_execution.node_selector_terms.match_expressions]]
                  key = "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
                  operator = "In"
                  values = [
                    "us-east-1c"
                  ]
```